# Selecting rows belonging to a relational database with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to fetch results from a sql query that will show all products that belong to multiple categories.

The relational table looks like this

```
category_id       product_id
23                72
33                72
43                72
23                32
33                18
```

So what I am trying to do for example is select all product_id's that belong to category_id 23,33,43. Which in this case would be only 72. Note I am trying to catch the products belonging to ALL the ids, not OR. So this qry wouldnt work

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p JOIN prod_to_cat AS pc ON p.products_id=pc.products_id IN(23,33,43)
```

So instead I tried

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p JOIN prod_to_cat AS pc ON p.products_id=pc.products_id WHERE pc.categories_id=23 AND pc.categories_id=33 AND pc.categories_id=43
```

It works perfectly if there is just one category, but whenever it becomes multiple, it will show no results.

I also looked here to find the solution and found one that suggested

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p JOIN prod_to_cat AS pc ON p.products_id=pc.products_id 
WHERE exists (select * from prod_to_cat c where c.products_id=p.products_id AND c.categories_id=23) 
AND exists (select * from prod_to_cat c where c.products_id=p.products_id AND c.categories_id=33)
AND exists (select * from prod_to_cat c where c.products_id=p.products_id AND c.categories_id=43)
```

But this seems to produce duplicate results.

So what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch only those products which must belong to categories say 6 and 18, then try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `prod_to_cat` WHERE `categories_id` IN (6, 18) GROUP BY `products_id` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `categories_id`) = 2 ORDER BY `products_id` ASC
```